# Setting cpu affinity for multipass

Tags: virtualization, cpu, multipass

I use [multipass](https://multipass.run/) via [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io).

With the environment variable `SNAPCRAFT_BUILD_ENVIRONMENT_CPU=12` I control how many cpus will be used by the VM.

However, I would like to set the affinity for the VM processors.

In my case ([i5-12600k](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=12600k)), I have 12 logical performance cores, and 4 physical efficiency cores.

I would like to constrain the CPUs used by multipass to the 12 logical performance cores.

Does either multipass or snapcraft have a control mechanism for this?

As it is now, the multipass processes jump all over cpu0 .. cpu15, but I want them on cpu0 .. cpu11 instead.

Comment: Take a look at the schedtool package for setting CPU affinity.

Comment: Ah, yes, it works after-the-fact too: `$ sudo schedtool -a 0xfff \`pidof multipassd\``

Answer (score 0):

In another way, you can manage multipass VM by virsh, and then use  `virsh vcpupin` to set cpu affinity for multipass.

You can ref ''[Multipass and libvirt VMs on Ubuntu, managed via Landscape](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/multipass-and-libvirt-vms-on-ubuntu-managed-via-landscape#3-install-multipass)'', this will help you to use `virsh` to manage multipass.

Good luck~